# How to followup several intents in Dialogflow using Webhook Tripadvisor API with Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I am creating an agent in Dialogflow for hotel booking using a [Tripadvisor API](https://rapidapi.com/apidojo/api/tripadvisor1?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=1674315309_71824013419&utm_term=trivagoapi_b).

Example:

**agent**: Hi, I can help you book a hotel room or **view your reservations**

**user**: Book a hotel room

**agent**: For what city?

**user**: Barcelona

**agent**: We recommend the hotel "Barcelona Hoteles". Do you want me to book?

**user**: **yes**

**agent**: Tell me your full name

**user**: Johnny Appleseed

**agent**: Ok, Johnny Appleseed. **I book at the "Barcelona Hotels" hotel**.

For this, I have created two followup intents depending on whether the user wants to book or not at the hotel recommended by the agent:

[image]

I am using ngrok to expose a local development server to the Internet.

What I want to achieve is that, by asking the user for their name, the entire reservation is stored in a MYSQL database (name, city in which it reserves, number of people, checkin, checkout ...) so that, once the user closes the interaction with the agent, by starting a conversation with him again, instead of wanting to make a reservation, the user wants to see his reservation, the agent reads his reservation from the database simply asking for his name. So to do this, I need to create another intent (follow up intent "yes", in the photo above it corresponds to "reservaIntent - yes") in order to obtain the full name of the user, but **how do I do this development in my Node.js project?**

This is the latest development of my code. Here I send the answer to Dialogflow saying that the recommended hotel for "x" is "x":

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  var json2 = JSON.parse(body);
  respuestaWebhook.fulfillmentText = 'For the city ' + city+ ' we recommend the hotel ' + json2.data[0].name + '. Do you want me to book?';
  res.json(respuestaWebhook);

// where "json2.data[0].name" is the name of the hotel received from de Tripadvisor API
```

So now, if the user answers "yes", when the agent asks for his name in the "followup intent - yes", **how do I collect that variable in my Node.js to later store it in my MYSQL database?**

I hope it's clear. Don't hesitate to ask me if there is something that has not been clear :)

Comment: The proposal of Abhinav makes sense to me. First, it is needed to take a decision based on what the user really wants. To manage the user's name, you can use [Parameters & entities](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/build-agent#use_parameter_data_in_a_response) Can you confirm if this resolves your question? if not, please share details on what could be the issue.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it.
The structure of my Agent in Dialogflow should be the following, correct?https://snipboard.io/Df3k0Z.jpg 
In Default Welcome Intent I ask the user "What do you want to do?" And that's when the user can choose whether to make a reservation or check an existing one, right?

Comment: Yes, I agree with the sequence of the image, it matches the recommendation of Abhinav. You can now collect the correct variable in the correct intent. So, let us know if this answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your situation here, then you need to change a bit in the approach here to make it easy.

Let me begin with 1st agent response, it seems like you are trying to handle to action within the same intent:

**agent**: *Hi, I can help you book a hotel room or view your reservations*

Ideally from here, there are two different conversations with different intent should take place.

one is for books that you are currently doing, another is to get the existing booking details:

So create two-parent intent :

1. **Create a booking:** You already handling it and making a successful booking.
2. **Get booking details:** It has one follow up intent askName to get the name and show the booking details. So, here it is how looks in conversation

**agent:** *Hi, I can help you book a hotel room or view your reservations*

**user:** *I want to check my reservation*

```
//This above response will be decision point to invoke either of intent (**create a booking or get reservation**)
```

**agent:** Tell me your full name

**user:** Johnny Appleseed

**agent:** *Ok, Johnny Appleseed. You have booking at hotel Barcelona on 31st Aug.*

It is very simple now to do it in Node JS as well. The conversation design is a bit different. You need to design each conversation flow like dialog.